# Alternatives for Delayed Chained Payments for Mobile

Tags: mobile, paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

We are currently using PayPal's Delayed Chained Payments for our website transactions (desktop). The problem is with our mobile transactions. We've considered the following solutions:

- Embedded Payment Flow (mini-browser) but the problem with this is that the minibrowser is buggy. It does not call the `returnUrl` or the `cancelUrl` after a transaction. And it does **NOT** support Chrome and Safari on iPhone
- We've also considered PayPal's Mobile SDK but the SDK for iOS does not support Adaptive Payments.

I was just thinking if there is a way to make a Delayed Payment using Express Checkout and not the Adaptive Payment. An example of the process flow:

> On an events website, a provider creates an event and posted an online registration.
>
> 1. On the first day, User A pays the fee. On the second day, User B and on the third day User C. Each payment is made using Express Checkout or Mobile Express Checkout.
> 2. Each time a user pays, the website's Paypal account holds the payment.
> 3. The event starts and three days after it started, the website would transfer all the funds or payments that it got to the event provider's PayPal account.

**Questions:** Is the process possible? Would the website still need to pay an additional transaction fee for the fund transfer? And would the website have a way to track which transaction payment it should forward to which provider?

I am a newbie on PayPal so please bear with me.